A formula for the $n^\text{th}$ power of elliptic-like integrands.
$$
\mbox{Define}\ \operatorname{F}\left(k,t\right) :=
\cos^{2}\left(t\right) + k^{2}\sin^{2}\left(t\right)\
\mbox{and}\ \operatorname{I}\left(n,k\right) :=
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left[\operatorname{F}\left(k,t\right)\right]^{n}{\rm d}t
$$
Using Maxima I evaluated this for various positive and negative integer values of $n$, and came across the following proposition:
$$
I(n,k)= \begin{cases}
 2^{-m(n)}P_{2n}(k)\quad\text{if}\quad n\in\mathbb Z^+ \\[2mm]
 2^{-m(n-1)}k^{-1}P_{2(n-1)}(k^{-1})\quad \text{if}\quad n\in \mathbb Z^- 
\end{cases}
$$
Here, $m\left(n\right) \in
\left\{1,2,4,5,8,9,11,12,\ldots\right\}$ and
\begin{align}
P_0(k) & = 1
\\[3mm]
P_2(k) & = k^2+1
\\[3mm]
P_4(k) & = 3k^4+2k^2+3
\\[3mm]
P_6(k) & = 5k^6+3k^4+3k^2+5,
\quad\text{&c.}
\end{align}
In general, $P_{2n}(k)\text{~}\mathcal{O}(k^{2n})$ is a  positive valued polynomial in $k^2$ whose coefficients can be arranged in a Pascal-like triangle:
$$
1\\
1\quad 1\\
3\quad 2\quad 3\\
5\quad 3\quad 3\quad 5\\
35\quad 20\quad 18\quad 20\quad 35\\
63\quad 35\quad 30\quad 30\quad 35\quad 63
$$
While the sequence $m(n)$ is easily found on OEIS, the triangle of coefficients of our polynomial are related to the numerators in expansion of $1/\sqrt{1-x}$ viz. $A001790$. Note that: $$I\big(-\frac{1}{2},k\big)=|k^{-1}|\frac{K\big(1-k^{-2}\big)}{\pi}$$ $$I\big(\frac{1}{2},k\big)=\frac{E\big(1-k^{2}\big)}{\pi}$$
Here $K(k)$ and $E(k)$ are respectively the complete elliptic integrals of first and second kinds. Three questions:
$1$.Is the proposition true?
$2.$If yes, can we prove it, either using geometry or analytically?
$3.$Does the result have any practical usage, in physics or elsewhere?

I think that writing $\cos^2=1-\sin^2$ and rewriting the polynomials in terms of $k^2-1$ as the variable, will help clean up the expressions.

At least for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, one can use the beta function:
Let $F(a,t)=\left(\cos^2t+a^2\sin^2t \right)$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(F(a,t)\right)^ndt =& \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\cos^2t+a^2\sin^2t \right)^ndt \\
=& \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}a^{2k}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2k}(t)\cos^{2n-2k}(t)\ dt \\
=& \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \frac{a^{2k}}{2} B\left(k+\frac12,n-k+\frac12\right) \\
=& \frac{\pi}{2^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n a^{2k}{{2k}\choose k}{{2n-2k}\choose{n-k}}
\end{align*}
and this is your polynomial.

The integrals are hypergeometric functions. Using Mathematica, one has Apell functions
$$\text{Assumptions}=n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>\, 0}\land 0<k<1\land 0<t<\frac{\pi }{2}$$
With
$$Q(k,t)=\left(1-k^2\right)\ \cos (2 t)+k^2+1 $$
$\text{Ig}(n, k, t) =$
$\text{PowerExpand@Simplify@Integrate}[(\cos (t)^2 + k^2 \sin(t)^2)^n, t]$
$$\frac{Q^{n+1}}{i\  2^{n+2}\ k \  (n+1)}\cdot F_1\left(n+1;\  \frac{1}{2},\ \frac{1}{2}; \ n+2;\ \frac{Q}{2 k^2},\ \frac{Q}{2}\right)$$
With factors neutralized, the definite integral yields  yields a confluent hypergeometric function
$$\begin{align}&\text{Jg}(n,k)=\text{FullSimplify}\left[\frac{(2 k) \ \left(\text{Ig}\left(n,k,\frac{\pi }{2}\right)-\text{Ig}(n,k,0)\right)}{i \  n!}\right]  = \\& \frac{i 2^{2 n-1} n n!}{\sqrt{\pi } k}\cdot \left(\, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2},n+1;n+\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{k^2}\right)-k^{2 n+2} \, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2},n+1;n+\frac{3}{2};k^2\right)\right)\end{align}$$
This definition yields the following list of polynomials after eliminating inverse trigonometrics, that arise for higher values of $n$
      Jg[Range[8], k] // FullSimplify // FunctionExpand // TrigToExp // 
            Together // FullSimplify // TableForm

$$\begin{array}{c}
 k^2+1 \\
 6 k^4+4 k^2+6 \\
 6 \left(5 k^6+3 k^4+3 k^2+5\right) \\
 4 \left(35 k^8+20 k^6+18 k^4+20 k^2+35\right) \\
 10 \left(63 k^{10}+35 k^8+30 k^6+30 k^4+35 k^2+63\right) \\
 12 \left(100 k^6+105 k^4+126 k^2+21 \left(11 k^4+6 k^2+5\right) k^8+231\right) \\
 28 \left(429 k^{14}+231 k^{12}+189 k^{10}+175 k^8+175 k^6+189 k^4+231 k^2+429\right) \\
 8 \left(6435 k^{16}+3432 k^{14}+2772 k^{12}+2520 k^{10}+2450 k^8+2520 k^6+2772 k^4+3432
   k^2+6435\right) \\
\end{array}$$
For negative integer $n$ there seems to be a problem for the evaluation of the boundary values, but limits work
$$\begin{align}& n\in \mathbb Z_{<0} : \quad  \underset{t \to \frac{\pi }{2}}{\text{lim}}\  \text{Ig}(n,k,t )-\underset{t \to 0}{\text{lim}}\ \text{Ig}(n,k,t ) =\\&\quad\quad \frac{i \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (n+2)}{2 k (n+1) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\cdot \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},n+1;n+\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{k^2}\right)-\frac{i \sqrt{\pi } k^{2 n+1} \Gamma (n+2)}{2 (n+1) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}\cdot \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},n+1;n+\frac{3}{2};k^2\right)\end{align}$$
